To resolve Meeting - Speaker Meeting is locked and cannot be deleted error while deleting a Meeting record
As i need to delete one Meeting Record created in 2020, but unable to delete since i am receiving this error. "Meeting - Speaker Meeting is locked and cannot be deleted".
Please find the reference image as well.

The Admin profile's has been already granted with CRED access, View All, Modify All for Meeting object from which i am deleting.
Also there is no validation rule in "Meeting" object which is throwing this errorr to delete.
So, can someone please help me to resolve this error?
Thanks,
Rudraswamy

This record is sent for approval.
Add a related list for approval history to see if there are any pending approval requests for the record.
After that you need to reject/approve the approval request and records should be unlocked.
Or you can check if record is locked, unlock record from apex Approval class

Ok, but the Meeting is in "Draft" status and the Workflow path is not configured to send for Approval.
